# jQuery Mobile Not Transitioning From Internal Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to link to an internal `id` within my jQuery Mobile web-app with a transition, however, jQuery Mobile does not appear to honor the transition attribute.

Here is my project: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B14/index.html

If you click on "Map" then on one of the map pins, an InfoBubble pops up that links to a new page. If you click on the info icon, the page does not transition.

Here is the HTML creating the link:

```
<a href="#africanMeetingHouse" data-transition="slide" class="mapToolTip">
<div class="mapToolTipText">African Meeting House</div>
<img src="Icons/info.png" class="infoIcon"></a>
```

Could this be a conflict with the Google Maps InfoBubble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this question:

I used the `changePage` function of jQuery Mobile:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#idToPage", {
    transition : "slide",
    reverse    : true
});
```